# Git adding hidden file, force doesn't work

Tags: git, hidden-files

I can't add the hidden file to git repo. Force (-f --force) does not help. This file is not included in .gitignore as well. It's silent (even with verbose flag) as the file is added, though it is not displayed in status, not actually added. File name is .profile, Is this name restricted for some reasons?

Comment: How do you add it?

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps ```git update-index``` is somehow involved. Don't know how git add would react if you had already specified that a file should be ```--asume-unchanged```.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer your question. Include the exact commands and outputs that you get in your question.

Comment: I tried `git add .profile` , `git add -f .profile` and `git add --force .profile` . I got no output. It does not appear on the tracked list. Actually it doesn't appear on untracked list as well. When I rename it for example to .prof it works. Surprisingly, other repo on my computer behaves normally with this file. It has rather nothing to do with .gitignore, as even deleting it doesn't help. I also rather didn't change any settings.

Comment: Well, when I typed `git rm .profile` it appeared on erased list. After copying this file again it started behaving normally. No clue what happened.

Comment: Well, that means that the file was already added and no changes had been made to it.

Answer (score 0):

No way, just check this repo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpyolang/.profile

Also make sure your global ignore file is ok.

`git config --global core.excludesfile`